# How to access Angular form element's attributes

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Let's say we have some form

```
<form name="myForm" data-ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <input name="input" data-ng-model="userType" data-description="User Type" required>
</form>
```

In controller, we can access that input element by code

```
$scope.myForm.userType
```

But how can we get data-* attributes of this element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
angular.element(selector).attr("data-description")
```

to select elements as you would do with jQuery.